# Why is this SHAP summary plot not showing in databricks?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, matplotlib, databricks, shap

When I run `shap.summary_plot(shap_values.values, X[input_cols]` or `shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X[input_cols])` databricks outputs

`<Figure size 576x684 with 2 Axes>`

The code used to work but the kernel restarted and running the same code no longer produces the plot.
I have an imported pipeline model and dataframe sampled from an rdd and run the following code before the above:

```
import shap
explainer=shap.TreeExplainer(pipelineModel.stages[2])#gradient boosting model from pyspark pipeline
shap_values=explainer(X,check_additivity=False)#X is a dataframe the model predicts on
```

I've printed the shap_values and X rows to verify that they contain the desired data and I'm able to run predictions on the data using the pipeline data. Why is this code now just producing <Figure size 576x684 with 2 Axes> instead of the actual figure? This problem persists whether matplotlib is used or not and shows up places other than SHAP. I've seen other answers for similar questions but using matplotlib=True on a summary plot just causes produces and error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why this is the solutions but

```
shap_fig=shap.summary_plot(shap_values.values, X[input_cols], show=False)

display(shap_fig)
```

displays the figure.